# German Tank Problem, Confidence Level

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you're in a city with n cabs. Each cab has a distinctive number from 0 to n. You take a cab 10 times, the choice of the cabs is independent and equiprobable. The cab with the biggest number has number 100.

Determine a preferably small upper limit for n with a confidence level of $\frac{9}{10}$.

To me, this sounds like the German Tank Problem. So, depending on the approach I get different estimates for n. But I don't know how to include the confidence level. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are numbered $0$ to $n$, that's $n+1$ numbers so there's one missing.  To make the problem nicer, I'll suppose they are numbered $1$ to $n$.

A statistic $L$ is an upper limit for $n$ with confidence level $p$ if for every possible $n$, $P(L \ge n) \ge p$.
In this case if $M$ is the maximum number observed and $L = c M$ where $c > 1$ is a constant, 
$$P(L \ge n) = P(M \ge n/c) = 1 - \left(\dfrac{\lceil n/c \rceil - 1}{n}\right)^{10} \ge 1 - \dfrac{1}{c^{10}}$$
To make the right side $9/10$, we want to take $c = 10^{1/10}$.  Thus for the observed $M = 100$
we would have $L \approx  125.89$, which could be rounded down to $125$.

Comment: I have two questions: Why $c > 1$ and not $c \ge 1$? 100 could have been the biggest number already?
And I don't understand how you get from $P(M\ge \frac{n}{c})$ to the next step. Could you please explain this?

Comment: OK, you could try $c = 1$ as well.  But $1 - 1/1^{10} = 0$, so that won't be the answer.  You want $P(M \ge n/c)$ to be at least $9/10$.